# STM32F0 with ADC and DMA with Renode

Tags: dma, adc, stm32f0, renode

I'm trying to run an application on Renode that uses ADC and DMA for the STM32F030F4P, I created a `stm32f0.repl` file with the `dma` and `adc` as follows:

```
dma: DMA.STM32LDMA @ sysbus 0x40020000
    [0] -> nvic@[9]

adc: Analog.STM32F0_ADC @ sysbus 0x40012400
    referenceVoltage: 3.3
    externalEventFrequency: 1000
    -> nvic@12
    dmaChannel: 1
    dmaPeripheral: dma
```

When I run Renode, I get the following error:

```
For parameter 'dmaPeripheral' of type 'Antmicro.Renode.Peripherals.DMA.IDMA' found attribute at C:\Program Files\Renode\platforms\cpus\stm32f0.repl:151:5 with value [ReferenceValue: dma]
  Parameter is not assignable from the reference value, constructor rejected.
  At C:\Program Files\Renode\platforms\cpus\stm32f0.repl:146:6:
  adc: Analog.STM32F0_ADC @ sysbus 0x40012400
       ^
```

What is the correct value for `dmaPeripheral`?

Answer (score 0):

As it's optional, you can remove it completely. This would lead to DMA not being used.

It seems that what you have written should be doable, and it's a bug that it's not possible. The `STM32LDMA` should implement the `IDMA` interface and it doesn't.

I would suggest filing a bug on [Renode's GitHub](https://github.com/renode/renode)

Disclaimer: I'm one of Renode developers